# Git How to: pull diff between branches

Tags: git, branch, diff, pull

I would like to download the files that are the difference between two branches into a local folder. Is it possible with Git?

Given the files are only added to the source branch, they are not changed.

Comment: Your question is unclear: you say "download" - does that mean you haven't cloned the repo? You need to do that before you can really do anything else.

Comment: Im interested in any solution. Lets say I have two branches in remote repo. What steps I should take to get a folder with the newly added files in it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get all changes between branches with something around these lines:

```
git diff origin/master origin/develop > my_diff.diff
```

If you only add [text] files, then it would be trivial to parse the diff file and break it into individual files. (I'd say, it's a ruby script under 50 lines of code)

Comment: You should put that on pastebin. It's hard to read as a comment. :)

Answer (score 8):

```
git archive --format=tar --prefix="exported/" -o export.tar br2 $(git diff --name-only br1 br2)
```

Assuming you're on `br2` right now and `br1` is lagging behind it, the part inside the brackets (`git diff...` )will give you the list of the files changed between the two heads. The `git archive` command will export these files as they are on `br2` (i.e. on your current head) to a tar file called `export.tar` inside a directory called `exported/`.

This assumes (like you stated in your question) that you've only added new files and that all the diffs are adds. The command will also export modified files but you claim not to have any.

Comment: I get 'error: unknown option `name-only''. Your assumption is correct only add.

Comment: `git diff --stat br1 br2 | grep \| | awk -F\| '{print $1}'` is a quick and dirty substitute if you don't have `--name-only`

Comment: Im writing a script for Sergei's answer. I'm almost done - it's 15 lines of code...

Comment: Cool. It's another thing to maintain though. Since git provides this, I think it's better to not write homebrew stuff.

Comment: `--name-only` has been around for a *really* long time - at the very least since v1.5. (Also `diff --numstat` is easier to parse, should you need to.)